# Animation is jerky, but slider is not

Tags: plotting, dynamic, manipulate, animation

When I do the following simple animation (from the book *Mathematica Navigator*, p. 316) the slider control changes the image smoothly, but when I play the animation it is jerky. Is there anything that can be done to make the animation smooth?

[image]

The code for the plot is as follows:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Cos[a x], {x, 0, 3 \[Pi]}], {a, 1, 10, 0.3}]
```

UPDATE: Changing the step value does not help; also, sometimes the animation stops completely, just gets stuck. Something appears to be seriously wrong with the animate function.

*The main problem, the jerkiness, appears to be caused by Windows "User Account Control" (UAC) (see answer below). This "security" feature is present in Windows 7, 8 and Windows Vista. It can be avoided by either running Mathematica as Administrator or by turning off Windows UAC altogether.*

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, but does the fixed step help? For example `{a, 1, 10, .01}`?

Comment: It does not help very much. There is still a lot of jerkiness, meaning that the animation does not play smoothly, but stops at random places and then resumes after a random delay.

Comment: Maybe there is a lot of other dynamic cells around which can slow it down? Have you tried on new notebook after reseting the kernel?

Comment: The example is from a new notebook after Mathematica is first opened. Nothing else is in the notebook.

Comment: Please do not put code into questions as an image. People don't like having to type your code into _Mathematica_, when with a little consideration on your part, you can provide your code in text which can be copied from the site and pasted into _Mathematica_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation showed this to be a problem when running Mathematica as a user under Windows 7. Under Windows XP and other environments the animation runs smoothly.

A workaround is to run Mathematica as Administrator on Windows 7 in which case there no UI pauses or animation pauses. Why running as an administrator makes a difference, I don't know.

Even running as administrator does not prevent the animation from stopping entirely at random points, but this appears to be from some different cause.

Comment: It might be an idea to specify Mathematica versions, OS configurations, memory, etc. somewhere (in the question, perhaps) - it's an interesting result!

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be an artifact of high speed updating of the plot. On my system, V9.0.1 running on OS X, the animation becomes smooth when `a` has an increment of `0.2` or larger. That is

```
Manipulate[Plot[Cos[a x], {x, 0., 3. \[Pi]}],
  {a, 1., 10., 0.2}]
```

looks smooth on my system. I think this because the problem becomes more noticeable as the value of `a` increases, and further, reducing the update speed with the Slower button when the animation is running will smooth it out.

Comment: Changing the step to 0.2 or 0.3 does not help in my case. Still jerky. Also, sometimes it stops entirely and just gets stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps generating the frames in advance would help create a smoother animation - but to my eyes there's not a huge difference - and there's a big wait at the beginning - it depends on what your use case is...

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[
  Plot[Cos[a x], {x, 0., 3. \[Pi]},
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {a, 1, 10, .01}]]
```

[image: listanimate]

Comment: This isn't an animated gif, for obvious reasons...:)