# Animate skips frames and hard to control speed.

Tags: graphics, animation, performance-tuning

I browsed similar questions related to `Animate` jerkiness like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34981/animation-is-jerky-but-slider-is-not), but haven't found the right options to control animation rate while also displaying all frames:

```
Animate[Prime[Range[400]] // Outer[(-Mod[#1, #2]/#2) &, # + k, #] & //
   Column@{Style[k, Large], 
     MatrixPlot[Transpose@#, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 600]} &, {k,
   1, 1000, 1}, AnimationRate -> 1]
```

[image]

- Even with smaller `ImageSize` occasionally a frame is skipped.
- `AnimationRate` is difficult to tune and some changes seem to have no effect.
- Alternatives like `ListAnimate` take too long to preprocess as noted by cormullion and others.

Comment: How about the option `DisplayAllSteps->True` of `Animate`?

Comment: Also check `ArrayPlot`, I think it is faster than `MatrixPlot`, and you might try to precompute stuff, like the `Prime[Range[400]]`, not big overhead, but you can keep the list in a variable. Also writing it all as an expression is slightly faster than with pure functions just applied once.

Comment: @halirutan, Im hesitant to accept below b/c I tried `DisplayAllSteps->True' with `AnimationRate->10` skips steps w/o actually speeding up the animation.

Answer (score 6):

There are some place which can be optimized in your animation. When I see this right, then your function

```
Outer[(-Mod[#1, #2]/#2) &, # + k, #] &
```

is similar to

```
Outer[(-Mod[#1+k, #2]/#2) &, #, #] &
```

but the latter has the big advantage, that the calculation of your `Outer` does not rely on `k`. It is even better than that, because now we can calculate the your whole prime matrix upfront exactly *one* time and use it over and over again.

To apply the `Mod` expression to each matrix element, I would compile it down and make it `Listable`. Let's start with that:

```
myMod = Compile[{{p, _Integer, 1}, {k, _Integer, 0}},
  -Mod[p[[1]] + k, p[[2]]]/(p[[2]]), CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

If you don't have a C compiler installed then just remove the `CompilationTarget` option. In the final animation, we pre-calculate the `data` matrix. This should make the approach faster. To display the matrix, I like to use `Image` exactly as Jens did, because it is made for speed. If you want to color it, then apply `Colorize` or any other function but be aware that this costs time too:

```
With[{data = Transpose[Outer[List, #, #] &@Prime[Range[400]]]},
 Animate[
  Column[{
    Style[k, Large],
    Image[Rescale@myMod[data, k]]
    }],
  {k, 1, 1000, 1}, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
 ]
```

The speed improvement is enormous on my machine here and **now** you can reduce the animation speed and you should see the change.

Comment: Thanks for working out all those improvements that I hadn't even considered, the metric was to minimize code size. These are worth pursuing for a larger version.

Comment: Something to keep in mind though is a comparison b/w Mathematica & C++ - to model benzene electronic structure I think - revealed a neck to neck, something like 5 hrs vs 5 1/2 hours -  so not necessarily worth compiling. The future --> VM optimization.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to plot large data in my experience is `Image`, as I do here:

```
Animate[Prime[Range[400]] // Outer[(-Mod[#1, #2]/#2) &, # + k, #] & //
   Column@{Style[k, Large], 
     Colorize[Image[Transpose@Rescale@#, ImageSize -> 600], 
      ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"]} &, {k, 1, 1000, 1}, 
 AnimationRate -> 1]
```

Comment: Nice. However, using `AnimationRate -> 10` skips steps while not actually speeding it up at all.

Comment: Yes, the truth is that for one-parameter list of images I usually would suggest pre-computing all images and using `ListAnimate`, but you already ruled that out in the question. The reason I prefer this is that you will often want to display the animation more than once anyway, and then it would be increasingly inefficient to re-do the necessary computations every time, the more often you intend to display them.

Comment: Good points, but during exploratory analysis you cannot afford that cold start - too slow. Wish there were an interface to map b/w the methods.