# Animate jerky after closing and opening section cell

Tags: animation, mac-os-x

[ Edit: 31 March 2015: I have just upgraded to Mathematica 10.1.0.0 and the problem (bug) is no longer present.]

Mathematica 10.0.1.0
Mac OS X 10.10.2 x86 
MacBook Pro late 2013

Consider the following simple Animate enclosed within a Subsubheading cell

Animate[Plot[Sin[a x],{x,0,2 Pi}], {a,-1,1}]

[image: Anitmate Example]

After evaluating the input cell, the animation runs very smoothly and can be stopped and started without altering the performance.

However, if the animation is stopped and the heading cell is closed and then re-opened, then upon restarting the animation it is very jerky.  The same happens if the animation is left running when the heading cell is closed.

On the other hand, if I stop the jerky animation and control it manually using the slider it is beautifully smooth!

This thread discussed a similar issue
[Animation is jerky, but slider is not](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34981/animation-is-jerky-but-slider-is-not)

but the cause was found to be with Windows 7: "Further investigation showed this to be a problem when running Mathematica as a user under Windows 7. Under Windows XP and other environments the animation runs smoothly."  So this does not address the problem I have identified.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I have just upgraded to Mathematica 10.1.0.0 and the problem (bug) is no longer present.

Answer (score 2):

I have just upgraded to Mathematica 10.1.0.0 and the problem (bug) is no longer present.